# How to put a Bundle inside a blob column in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, serialization, blob

I have this bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("u", mp); // String mp
bundle.putSerializable("m", mealplan); // String[7][6][4][5] mealplan
save.putExtra("b", bundle);
```

I need to put it inside a blob column but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: blob accept array string type data.. like image array something like that. we used blob for this purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle` objects support `Parcel`s, but the [`Parcel.marshall()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#marshall()) says:

> The data you retrieve here **must not** be placed in any kind of persistent storage (on local disk, across a network, etc). For that, you should use standard serialization or another kind of general serialization mechanism. The Parcel marshalled representation is highly optimized for local IPC, and as such does not attempt to maintain compatibility with data created in different versions of the platform.

The easist serialization mechanism probably is JSON, which is a readable text format.
To create a JSON string, you have to construct a tree of `JSONObject`/`JSONArray` objects:

```java
// write
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("u", mp);
JSONArray mealplan_json = new JSONArray();
mealplan_json.put(...); // fill arrays recursively
json.put("m", mealplan_json);
String text = json.toString();

// read
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);
mp = json.getString("u");
JSONArray mealplan_json = json.getJSONArray("m");
...
```

If you want to save space with a binary encoding, you have to use serialization, which supports basic types and any object that correctly implements [java.io.Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

```java
// write
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(mp);
oos.writeObject(mealplan);
oos.close();
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

// read
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
mp = (String) ois.readObject();
mealplan = (String[][][][]) ois.readObject();
```

Please note that this binary serialization does not store any key names ("u", "m"), so you have to ensure that all versions of your app write and read the same objects in the same order.

If you want to have a key/value structure, you have to implement your own helper functions that write values with a separate key string in front, and that read an arbitrary number of key/value pairs into a map.
Alternatively, create your own serializable object that contains the desired elements (and take care that this class stays compatible in future versions of your app):

```java
class MealPlanData implements Serializable {
    String u;
    String[][][][] mp;
};
```

If you have only a `Bundle` object and do not know its structure, you have to handle the keys/values manually:

```java
// write
oos.writeInt(bundle.size());
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
    Object value = bundle.get(key);
    oos.writeObject(key);
    oos.writeObject(value);
}

// read
int size = ios.readInt();
Map<String, Object> map = new ArrayMap<String, Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String key = (String) ios.readObject();
    Object value = ios.readObject();
    map.put(key, value);
}
```